# Docker RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get

Tried to build my own docker, got a little problem, here's the log
i was following the tutorial on Docker.

```
FROM docker/whalesay:lateset
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

This happened after RUN apt-get...

```
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_source_Sources.gz is not what the server reported 213537 7925687
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 11688 7588885
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Maybe you just misspelled FROM docker/whalesay:lateset, which should be latest.

Comment: Wouldnt have let him get to the next step in the build if that was the issue

Answer (score 1):

run this command before `apt-get update`:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You've run out of space. Or more precisely, the amount of space dedicated to docker assets has been exceeded.

Try this (on the host machine):

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Or this: https://hub.docker.com/r/martin/docker-cleanup-volumes/

Answer (score 1):

Adding `apt-get clean` before the `apt-get update` solves my problem. You can try it.

The Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

Comment: This solved a similar problem: I was attempting to install mingw-w64 on a node:14 runtime and I couldn't get past the sourcing / downloading step. Could you expand on your answer if you know why apt-get clean is a fix?